# Automatically printing the value of the last expression in GDB, like VisualStudio's "Auto" watch window

Tags: c++, linux, gdb

VisualStudio's debugger has a feature called [Auto Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290702%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), which always display the value of the current and previous expression.  Is there a way to acieve similar behavior in GDB, especially for C++ apps?

I'm aware of the `display` and `commands` commands in GDB, but they don't appear to be what I'm looking for.  In VS, the debugger automatically figures out which expression to evaluate and then evaluates it, with every step through the program.  This functionality -- automatically figuring out what expression to evaluate -- is what I want GDB to do.

For example, suppose I'm stepping through this code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s = "Hello";
    s += "World";

    int i = 2;
    i *= 3;
    i *= 7;

    stringstream ss ;
    ss << "The result is " << i << "!\n";
    ss << "Now, what was the question?";

    s += ss.str();

    cout << s << endl;

}
```

... and I'm about to execute the `i*=7` line.  In VS's Autos window, I see:

[image]

Is there a way to get GDB to show me the value of the current and previous exppressions, whatever they may be, as is shown in the Autos window here?  **Edit** Note that I didn't type `i` in to the screenshot above -- the debugger did that for me, and it displays potentially difference expressions with every step through the program.  That automatic display is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It's a long time since I used "ddd" (which is an application that runs on top of GDB to give you GUI functionality), but it MAY give you what you want - it certainly shows nicely what line you are executing and can show local variables in a separte window, etc. 
[ddd](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/)

There are probably other GUI layers for GDB as well, if you go looking.

Otherwise, display is probably the closest you'll get, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [display](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb-5.1.1/html_node/gdb_56.html) command to do what you want. You can also use the [commands](http://www.ofb.net/gnu/gdb/gdb_35.html) command to execute a list of commands when you hit a breakpoint.

Comment: How can I use `display` to display the last expression, *whatever it may be*?

Comment: Note that in my screenshot above, I didn't enter `i` as an expression to evaluate -- the debugger did that for me.

Comment: Actually, it appears I misread your question. I believe my answer is the closest you can get to having the previous value of an expression evaluated and automatically displayed and for that, you will have to specify exactly what you want to be "auto-displayed" using the display command.

When you type next/step or any variant, whatever you have in your display list that is in scope, is displayed. GDB remembers the last command you typed, so you can just hit enter and execute the last command, in this case it would be a next/step variant.